# Do a postback in jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

This has been already asked by many SO users and have solutions also. But none of them is working for me.

In aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function inPageLoad() {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () {

            //Confirmation Dialog
            $(document).on('click', '#btnConfirm', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                  .html('<div><h6>Yes or No?</h6></div>')
                  .dialog({
                      modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                      width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                      buttons: {
                          Yes: function () {
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                              __doPostBack('btnConfirm','');
                          },
                          No: function () {
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                          }
                      },
                      close: function (event, ui) {
                          $(this).remove();
                      }
                  });
            });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(inPageLoad);

</script>
```

In aspx.cs

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeFunction();
}
```

I want to do a postback(go to 'btnConfirm_Click' event in codebehind) if the click is 'Yes'. Eventhough the dialog popups nicely it doesn't do the postback. All help appreciated!

Comment: Did you check for any javascript error ?

Comment: DId you debug it and confirm that `doPostBack` is really being executed? Any errors in console?

Comment: @Andrei, yes there is an error `inPageLoad is not defined`. But since the dialog popuped well i ignored that. Is it the reason?

Comment: Nope, that is the error for your line `$(document).ready(inPageLoad);`. You can remove it - it is invalid and not needed anyway. My question was more about what happens after you click the button. So again, did you debug it?

Comment: @Andrei, yes i did debug it. if i put a breakpoint(in firebug) on `$(document).on('click', '#btnConfirm', function (e) `  eventhough the dialog popuped it didn't hit the break point

Comment: @Isuru, you need to put the breakpoint inside the Yes function. If you click "yes" on the popup and this breakpoint is not hit, that means you failed to subscribe to the Yes button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of   `__doPostBack('btnConfirm','')`;

```
 Yes: function () {
  $("[id*=btnConfirm]").click();
 },
```

UPDATING MY ANSWER

> Take another button, with display none property and trigger that
>   Button

css

```
.hidden
{
display:none;
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:Button id="btnhidden" runat="server" onclick="btnhidden();" cssClass=hidden/>
```

javascript

```
  Yes: function () {
      $("[id*=btnhidden]").click();
     },
```

Comment: what excalty happen when button is trigger ?

Comment: Then because of the btnConfirm's click event is triggered again it again comes to `$(document).on('click', '#btnConfirm', function (e) { }`. Becomes repetitive.

Comment: so take another button make it display none and trigger that button and write your code on that.

Comment: Thanks! It worked although it seems like a workaround. I wasn't able do a postback directly within the dialog. If you can, please change your original answer to reflect the changes you suggested. Then i can mark it as answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Isuru updated my answer.Yes it is something like workaround

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't work for my situation, so I want to give people an alternative in case they end up in the same situation I was in - the below worked for me:

The event I wanted to raise was coming from an Button click within a repeater - so it made my situation unique. The following is the markup I ended up using:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPersonRemove" Style="width: 15px" Text="Remove" OnClientClick="return confirmation(this);" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
```

With this panel (outside of the repeater):

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirmationMessage" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="confirmation">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPersonID" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblConfirm" runat="server">Are you sure you'd like to remove this member?</asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

Notice that I'm passing `this` to the JS and returning the result from the `confirmation` method. You'll see below that passing `this` allows me to retrieve the unique ID from the clicked control by using the JS `.name` property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        $("#<%= pnlConfirmationMessage.ClientID %>").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             modal: true,
             resizable: false,
             draggable: false
         });
     });

     function confirmation(control) {
         $("#<%= pnlConfirmationMessage.ClientID %>").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
             'Confirm': function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 return evaluate(true, control);
             },
             'Cancel': function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 return evaluate(false, control);
             }
         });

         $("#<%= pnlConfirmationMessage.ClientID %>").dialog('open');
     }

     function evaluate(value, control) {
         if (value) {
             __doPostBack(control.name, '');
         }
     }
 </script>
```

Note that we're not binding the buttons to the jQuery dialog box until the event is actually raised. This delays the postback from actually occurring until the user interacts with the dialog box.

If they click 'Confirm' in the jQuery UI dialog box, we call the `evaluate(value)` method and pass `true` to it; if they click 'Cancel' we pass `false`.

The `__doPostBack(id, eventArg)` is what initiates the postback with the button click event attached to it from `control.name`.

Although this is from within a Repeater, I could see it being applied to other situations as well. Hope this can help someone.